# Champion vs. Thief Damage Comparison

Tags: damage, rogue, pathfinder-2e, thief, champion

I am new to Pathfinder 2e. I am absolutely not familiar with the Champion, and just a little bit with the Thief.

How do the Champion and Thief compare regarding damage output (at level 1, 5, 10, and 15)?

We have a Shelyn Champion. Paladin [Lawful Good], glaive (two-handed, so no shield); the Thief uses rapier and dagger with Sneak. Archetypes are not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to PF2e ruedi! I hope you enjoy the system :)

We need a little more parameters to answer this question. What [Champion cause](https://2e.aonprd.com/Causes.aspx) are we using? Are we assuming the target is flat footed (for Sneak Attack, etc.)? Will the Champion be able to use their Champion reaction? What weapons are we using? (The highest damage Champions are probably using a 2h weapon, but many Champion builds use a shield, limiting that). Are archetypes allowed? 

Lots of questions, I know.

Comment: Absolute resonable questions. Since we have a Shelyn Champion. Paladin[Lawful God], Glaive (two handed so no shield), The Thief uses Rapier and Dagger with Sneak. Archetypes are not allowed. I hope that I gave all needed information.

Comment: Are we able to assume the champion gets to use their Retributive Strike reaction? And is the champion striking against a flat-footed enemy as well?

Comment: Yes you can assume both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Damage Comparison

### The Chart:

[image: Paladin beats all Rogue permutations in damage]

### The Summary:

Paladin outdamages Rogue at all levels except for level 5, when the Rogue has [Double Slice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=356) (e.g. from the [Dual Weapon Warrior](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=57) archetype). However, said Rogue keeps pace such that the difference is minimal. Attacks are against a Flat-Footed [Moderate AC](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1009) enemy of the same level

### Chart Explanation:

The Paladin, according to the parameters stated in the question, is making 3 attacks on their turn with a glaive, and taking one attack using their Retributive Strike each round. I assumed no feats nor other abilities from either character, with the exception of giving the Rogue Double Slice for some of the calculations. A Rogue using a dagger and rapier doesn't actually benefit from using the dagger except as part of Double Slice; otherwise the damage die decrease plus absence of the Deadly trait means that a dagger only outdamages a rapier minimally in a few scenarios at higher level. I did include a line on the Thief only striking with their rapier, or striking with their rapier for the first action and then a short sword for the next two. The third attack on the Double Slice Rogue with a rapier plus short sword is also a short sword attack.

### But, Why?

The parameters of this question do heavily favor the Paladin; Rogues have a lot of ways to get the Flat-Footed condition easier (e.g. [Dread Striker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=561), [Gang Up](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=567)) that wouldn't work the Paladin, and guaranteeing the Paladin their reaction every round is quite generous. Additionally, this doesn't account for other damage increasing abilities; Thief Rogues can get [Precise Debilitations](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=578), which adds a large chunk of extra damage. The Paladin has options to increase their damage, but they tend to be much more situational (e.g. only effective vs evil creatures, like [Smite Evil](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=230) or [Blade of Justice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=244)).

### So which class does more damage?

The classes in a realistic situation are probably going to be similar in terms of damage, at least before feats are considered. Their biggest differentiation is not their damage, but rather their playstyle; Champions are very defensive, with a high AC and the ability to protect allies from effects. Rogues are a bit squishier (8 health per level vs the Champion's 10), but make up for that by being extremely good at Skills, and having more of a "skirmisher" feel. Their debilitations at higher levels will make them feel more like a controller/debuffer than the Champion as well.

*NB: Yes, the Double Slice calculations technically ignore the "no archetypes allowed" rule. But if you are serious about two-weapon fighting on a rogue, Double Slice at 2 is basically a necessity. [Twin Feint](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=552) at level 1 does help a little bit, but you'll generally be better off stepping into flanking position and Double Slicing.*

Comment: How do you account for differences in critical rates? If a rogue is getting sneak attack every attack, we can assume the target is flat-footed, effectively giving the rogue a +10% chance to hit and crit compared to the champion.

Comment: @ruedi specified that they Champion also was striking a flat-footed target in the comments on the question. So, I don't :) removing flat-footed from the Champion gives the Rogue a significant edge, but it's a little overly simplistic to run damage numbers saying that Rogue _always_ has flat-footed while the Champion _never_ has it, especially given that flanking is easy enough for both of them.

Comment: @MikeQ I would think the most complete way to do it is compare non-flat-footed damage and flat-footed damage, and maybe rogue flat vs champion non-flat as a third choice (only because, as ESCE points out, rogues have various ways to get flat-footed that don't apply to allies).

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me, playing a Thief rogue with a Champion in the party... but they're also a shield tank, not a glaive wielder. So that's a pretty significant difference haha

Comment: @Ifusaso I also bet your Champion doesn't proc their reaction every single round, and doesn't spend all three actions attacking. I ran the calculations against a moderate AC flat-footed enemy as well... so the presence/absence of Deadly and the viability of attacking 3 times is definitely overemphasized from actual play.

Comment: @Ifusaso - does your play experience see your Rogue outdamaging the Champion significantly? Or other way? I'm curious, as my group has a similar situation where our Thief Rogue seems like they outdamage our Trident + Shield fighter. (Also... are the runes equivalent?)

Comment: We have both (usually) had level appropriate weapon runes; I have recently acquired Shock that he didn't have. At level 18ish, I'm regularly hitting for about 40-60 (and critting for close to 100) once a round and usually hitting twice. With Double Deb, I most often keep them Flat Footed and taking increased Precision damage. He uses hammer type weapons (currently a warhammer) for about 30 once or twice per round, sometimes a third. He uses his Reaction essentially every round but isn't always in a position to make the attack; probably about 2/3 the time.

Comment: The 1-2 attacks are his normal and Reaction attack, then the -5 attack is pretty unreliable

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time you invested! That is very intersting and helpful! I can take the Dual-Weapon Warrior Dedication at Level 2 instead of a Class Feat, right?

Comment: @Ifusaso ahhh yeah; that debilitation combo is nasty. I do think feats will launch the Thief rogue well into the upper tiers of melee damage, beyond the champion.

Comment: @ruedi My pleasure! I hope you are able to make a character you enjoy! Yes, you can take an archetype instead of a class feat; most archetypes start at level 2, but some are later (like Shadowdancer). Here are the archetype rules if you are curious: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=167